# SAN(FC) Storage does not work with VmWare

Tags: networking, vmware, san

I'm having trouble with SAN Switch and VMware. The situation is as follows. I have 2x HP MSA SAN Switch 32port, 2x servers, 2 SANs storage (IBM, HP). Both servers see both storages. It's okay. Now, I want to add additional third server, but this one cannot see the storage. I think that zoning in the switch I set properly, but it does not work. Topology is placed in the attachment. According to the diagram, I think that second switch is used as a backup if first stops working. Both switches are set to the same (except WWN of course), the same aliases, same zoning. Aliases are set far more than are actually connected devices (many servers in the server room are not already there). Just 3. So I deleted on one switch settings (aliases, zoning ...) and set new, but it does not work. Added third server sees only HP Fibre Channel RAID array controller. But no HP/IBM storage. And it is interesting that when I deleted one switch, so the two servers still see storage at both FCs, while I think that one side should disappear. Screens from Vmware are in attachments.
Thanks for help

screens:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5aU_GbEEHQdLVYzMkdDU1U1MFU?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm unable to access the image on Google Drive. Please post the topology as a regular image. Also, please try to increase the legibility of your post.